# Team mode on when on mobile

Tags: agar.io

I seem to have my team mode turned on while playing on my mobile as everyone is yelling at me to "PLZ TEAM" the entire time. I've never played on anything but mobile. Anyways I can turn it off to avoid being the never ending bad guy??

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a team mode on or off. There is a separate game mode but the teams split into like 3 colors and try to get the most mass. When people say "plz team" they want to collect mass with you and save each other from enemies and stuff and them ultimately absorb you cause why not. So just ignore it because they want to use you to get big most of the time.